# Как правильно реализовать двусвязный список на массивах?

Tags: c#, коллекции, linked-list

Получил в университете задание - реализовать класс LinkedList на языке C#, используя только одномерные массивы. Очевидная реализация с помощью хранения ссылок на соседние элементы отпадает, согласно ТЗ, а использование одномерного массива внутри полностью убивает все прелести связного списка с точки зрения вычислительной сложности операций над ним. Существует ли способ реализовать двусвязный список на одномерных массивах, не потеряв в вычислительной сложности?

Comment: взять одномерный массив и хранить в значении элемента списка  свободный индекс массива, т.е ссылку на индекс следующего элемента массива. Обратную связь по тому же принципу.

Comment: в такой реализации, насколько я понимаю, будет страдать удаление элемента из списка.

Comment: если этот элемент из массива физически не удалять после каждого удаления, а просто помечать как свободный индекс массива, то ничего страдать не будет. Физическое удаление можно применять изредко для хвостовых элементов массива

Comment: Очень удобно, если все элементы списка будут одного размера. Тогда сначала делайте на тех же элементах массива список свободных и работаете с ним. Т.е. у вас будет заголовок из 3-х переменных -- начало списка свободных (по нему же вы возвращаете удаляемые данные), начало вашего двусвязного списка и 3-я переменная -- его последний элемент. Список свободных лучше делать односвязным (меньше операций)

Comment: @avp а зачем при одинаковых элементах список свободных? при удалении элемента переносим на его место самый дальний и сдвигаем указатель на начало свободной области к началу на длину элемента, ну не забываем поправить линки, сложность O(1). С элементами разной длины такой фокус уже не пройдет и действительно нужен список.

Comment: @rdorn, как раз для того, чтобы ничего не сдвигать, а только манипулировать несколькими индексами.